# Strip space on either side of word

Tags: python, regex

How would I do the equivalent of `str.strip()` using regex?

So far I have:

```
>>> s = ' Luca Bercovici (characters) '
>>> re.sub('^\s|\s$','',s)
'Luca Bercovici (characters) '
```

This seems to remove all leading whitespace, but not trailing whitespace.

This looks ok: `re.sub('^\s+|\s+$','',s)`

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Why don't you use `s.strip()`?

Comment: I have a few other things I need to replace as well, the extra whitespace is just part of it.

Comment: I understand you want to do all your processing in one shot but in the interests of readability it might be better to do your processing in stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, why aren't you just using `.strip()` normally?

---

That said, your existing code works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ' Luca Bercovici (characters) '
>>> re.sub('^\s|\s$','',s)
'Luca Bercovici (characters)'
```

That said, if you have more than a single whitespace character on one end, you'd need to extend your pattern to match more than one:

```
re.sub('^\s+|\s+$','',s)
```